# RecyclerView: Load Ahead Of Visibility

Tags: android, caching, android-recyclerview

In my app, I have a recyclerview that loads images from mp3 meta data and places them into their viewholder in my app.

However, when scrolling fast you can clearly see that the RV cannot keep up, even when the loading happens on another thread.

The standart image for the viewholder is visible for a split second, then a little lag occurs and then the image gets replaced with the correct one.

However, when the user scrolls back up, everything is fine since the items are mostly still in cache.

How would I manage to get the "cache" to be ahead before the user scrolls?

So say the user starts the app and is at pos 0.
Visible are elements 0 - 10.
As soon as the user now scrolls, item 11 becomes visible and needs loading. But I want that to be already loaded before the scroll happens so:

User is at pos 0. Visible are items 0 - 10 and loaded are items 0 - 25.
When the user NOW scrolls, the RV loads items 25-30 even thou only items 5 - 15 are currently visible. So the RV loads ahead.

How would one go on about this?

Thank you and cheers.

Comment: Maybe using https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/ will improve your use case, but fast scrolling work pretty much the same way on most apps. If your dataset it´s not very big or you don't mind caching lots of information, you could launch a process constrained by the wifi to pre-download every mp3 metadata image, but not so sure this is a clean way to solve your problem.

Comment: Also this link could be useful https://medium.com/google-developers/recyclerview-prefetch-c2f269075710

Comment: hi, thank you. but i am loading the data from within my phones disk.

Answer (score 0):

I was being smart:

```
public class PreCachingLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager
{
     private const int DEFAULT_EXTRA_LAYOUT_SPACE = 1000;
     private int extraLayoutSpace = -1;
     private Context context;

     public PreCachingLayoutManager(Context context) : base(context)
    {
         this.context = context;
     }

     public void setExtraLayoutSpace(int extraLayoutSpace)
     {
         this.extraLayoutSpace = extraLayoutSpace;
     }

     protected override int GetExtraLayoutSpace(RecyclerView.State state)
     {
         if (extraLayoutSpace > 0)
         {
             return extraLayoutSpace;
         }
         return DEFAULT_EXTRA_LAYOUT_SPACE;
     }
}

        mLayoutManager = new PreCachingLayoutManager(this);
        mLayoutManager.ItemPrefetchEnabled = true;
        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```